# Custom reference types, e.g. \fref{figure_1} renders (Fig. 1)

Tags: hyperref, ref

As indicated in the title, I would like to customize the appearance of my references. Currently I am using something like this:

```
(\hyperref[fig:figure_ref_name]{Figure \ref{fig:figure_ref_name}.A})
```

Which renders:
(Figure 1.A)

I would like to shorten this command into:

```
\fighref{figure_ref_name}
```

with an optional argument for the case of subfigures, such as

```
\fighref{figure_ref_name, A}
```

and without hyperref:

```
\figref{figure_ref_name,A}
```

I also want to extend this to other cases, e.g. (Eq. 1), etc...

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Thanks! I improved the question format based on your tip.

Comment: I don't really know if is enough for your requirements, but you might want to have a look at `cleveref` (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref).

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example. This is much more helpful than fragments of code. It isn't clear, for one thing, how you're loading `hyperref`. Apparently, you are switching off some of the default linking, though I'm not sure why. You might also look at `fancyref` which provides `\fref`. But why are you not using the facilities `hyperref` provides for linked and non-linked cross-references? You shouldn't need to use `\hyperref` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I would instead use the `cleveref` package. This package will automatically insert the type of the reference (Fig., Tab., Section  etc.) along with the number.

To get the parenthesis, you could wrap this into a simple macro. In principle one could add an optional argument to this macro to insert the `A` (`\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\crefp}[2][]{(\cref{#2}\ifstrempty{#1}{}{.#1})}`), but again I would avoid reinventing the wheel, with packages like `subcaption` one can automatically reference to a specific subfigure.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\crefp}[1]{(\cref{#1})}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\cref{fig:1}

\cref{fig:1a}

\crefp{fig:1}

\crefp{fig:1a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works. The problem with subfigure is that it requires for the figures to be separate images, but I normally have all subfigures in one image, so I will use the custom command.

Comment: @SeptimusG The `subcaption` package also has solution for this situation, please have a look at the section about `\phantomsubcaption` in the package manual.